# How to get SharePoint Group Names having permission on Folder in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I have a document library and it has nested folder structure. Each Folder has Unique permission and some SP groups have been to them. How can I get the list of the SP groups having permission on the particular folder using client scripts only (SPSeriveces/REST API/JSOM)?

Thanks.

Comment: by client script do you mean browser based scripting or you can go with C# client side object model as well?

Comment: only browser based scripting.

Comment: Hi, i added the JSOM port of same code written in CSOM. Kindly check that. Inside currentFolder, you'll get all the roles. You need to extract from that.

Answer (score 1):

That's a rat's nest.

I don't think that this can be done with SPServices, REST or JSOM, especially least not in 2010, where there is no JSOM.

You will need Powershell for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer CSOM as a solution you can use following script to read the folder permissions:

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://server:port/sites/test");
Web web = ctx.Web;
List test = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test Docs");
ListItemCollection itemColl = test.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllFoldersQuery());
ctx.Load(itemColl, x => x.Include(y => y.RoleAssignments.Include( z=> z.Member), y => y.DisplayName));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (ListItem item in itemColl)
{
    Console.Write(item.DisplayName + " folder permissions are: ");
    foreach (RoleAssignment role in item.RoleAssignments)
    {
        Console.Write(role.Member.Title + "\t");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
}
```

**Edit**
JSOM port of above code.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetFolderGroupPermissions, 'sp.js');
var allFolders;
function GetFolderGroupPermissions(){
    debugger;
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test Docs');
    var folderQuery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllFoldersQuery();
    allFolders = list.getItems(folderQuery);
    ctx.load(allFolders, 'Include(DisplayName, RoleAssignments, RoleAssignments.Include(Member))');
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        var allFolderEnum = allFolders.getEnumerator();
        while(allFolderEnum.moveNext()){
            var currFolder = allFolderEnum.get_current();
            var roles = currFolder.get_roleAssignments();
            var allRoles = roles.getEnumerator();
            console.log(currFolder.get_displayName());
            while(allRoles.moveNext()){
                var currentRole = allRoles.get_current();
                console.log(currentRole.get_member().get_loginName());
            }

        }
    }, function(){})
    console.log(ctx);
}
```

Kindly note, the first console log will provide you the Folder Name, while the second console log will give you folder/user permission.

Comment: You can execute this script outside of SP farm as its Client Side Solution, just refer to SP client and runtime dll.