# Sharepoint REST Service For loop

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api

Can any one help me to how can I pass `lstURL`, `lstTitle` every `for each` loop through this function `mergePartsWithInventoryLocations`

My problem is I am getting last loop list name and url only not every loop.

Please help me on this.

```
function getListItems(lstNames, siteurl, success, failure) {
    var MCategory = '';
    var Mcate = '';
    if (ddlCategyOpt == "Policy") {
        Mcate = 'A';
    }
    if (ddlCategyOpt == "Guideline") {
        Mcate = 'B';
    }

    if (ddlCategyOpt == "All") {
        Mcate
    }
    var lstTitle = '';
    var lstUrl = '';
    for (var x = 0; x < lstNames.length; x++) {
        lstUrl = 'https://epecm.petronas.com.my' + lstNames[x].LURL;
        lstTitle = lstNames[x].LTitle;
        if (ddlCategyOpt != "All") {
            $.ajax({
                url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'" + lstNames[x].LGUID + "')/items?$Filter=Mandatory_x0020_Category eq  '" + Mcate + "'",
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {
                    note = '';
                    var parts = data.d.results;
                    mergePartsWithInventoryLocations(parts, lstTitle, lstUrl);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    failure(data);
                }

            });

        }
        else {

            $.ajax({
                url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'" + lstNames[x].LGUID + "')/items",
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {
                    note = '';
                    var parts = data.d.results;
                    mergePartsWithInventoryLocations(parts, lstTitle);

                },

                error: function (data) {
                    failure(data);
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing the issue due to ajax call, by the time ajax call return and process, your function execution complete. To avoid such situation we use the concept of `Closures`. Kind [follow the link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) to know more about closures.

In your case, simply take out the entire code within `for loop` and create another function with that. Call that function in for loop and your problem will be solved.

**Edit**
Try the following code.

```
function getListItems(lstNames, siteurl, success, failure) {
    var MCategory = '';
    var Mcate = '';
    if (ddlCategyOpt == "Policy") {
        Mcate = 'A';
    }
    if (ddlCategyOpt == "Guideline") {
        Mcate = 'B';
    }

    if (ddlCategyOpt == "All") {
        Mcate
    }
    var lstTitle = '';
    var lstUrl = '';
    for (var x = 0; x < lstNames.length; x++) {
        lstUrl = 'https://epecm.petronas.com.my' + lstNames[x].LURL;
        lstTitle = lstNames[x].LTitle;
        if (ddlCategyOpt != "All") {
            var queryData = "?$Filter=Mandatory_x0020_Category eq  '" + Mcate + "'";
            getFilteredItems(siteurl, lstNames[x].LGUID, lstTitle, lstUrl, queryData)
        }
        else {
            getFilteredItems(siteurl, lstNames[x].LGUID, lstTitle, null, "");
        }
    }
}

function getFilteredItems(siteurl, listGUID, lstTitle, lstUrl, query){
    $.ajax({
        url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'" + listGUID + "')/items" + query,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            note = '';
            var parts = data.d.results;
            mergePartsWithInventoryLocations(parts, lstTitle, lstUrl);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you kind answer let me do and get back to you

Comment: Dear Boss kindly please help me to change my code and send..i have been try but still could not achive.

Comment: I had update the answer with code now. Try to execute it. If you got any JS issue (variable undefined, then please check the code once as i didnt test it). Also in case of error, please log it here. Also try to do `console log` in ajax success function and send the output screen shoot.

Comment: Dear Boss Really thanks you very much for your help.now it is working...your really great

Comment: Welcome, i am glad it helped you out. You can mark it as answer so other people can take advantage of same.

Comment: Yes this is good help to others also

Comment: Dear Boss would like to check with you that would need to get group name and user with permission for the sub site in sharepoint using client side (javascript)  model .do you have any ides please share wth me ..Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Follow the URL. It is for getting folder permission but you can use the same logic to get site/subsite permissions. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219046/how-to-get-sharepoint-group-names-having-permission-on-folder-in-sharepoint-2010/219083#219083

Comment: Boss can i have your whats up number or any other number to call you.plss

Comment: track me on twitter